# Why is my unmounted USB disk still seen by `fdisk`?

Tags: linux, mount, usb-drive

I've mounted my USB disk to `/mnt/kingston/` dir, and umounted it from there by typing in `umount /mnt/kingston/`.

But I can still see my USB disk after issuing the `fdisk -l` command. Why?

If I type in `umount /mnt/kingston` again, it shows: `umount: /mnt/kingston; not mounted`.

Comment: It's right: try to umount any HDD partition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you mount a partition, it will show in `df -h`, and if you umount it, then it will no longer show in `df -h`

`fdisk -l` uses `/proc/partitions` and prints out all partitions which are physically connected, but your USB drive is still connected to your PC. When you unplug it, then it will not show in `fdisk -l` anymore, and you can also check  `cat /proc/partitions` for the same.

I think you are thinking from a Windows perspective, if not then let me know I will remove below content.

Let me clear these things:

- `df -h` is the same as when you open Explorer (My Computer) and
- `fdisk -l` is same same as the Device Manager and Disk Management.

After disconnecting(safely removed) a USB device in windows, it will still be shown in "Device Manager" under Universal USB Bus Controller

Comment: But in windows, if I unpluged the USB drive, neither will it show in the Device Manager nor Disk Management...:)

Comment: disconnect means safely remove . not physically disconnect

Comment: @Rubby, Windows turn off power of unmounted USB port. Linux don't do such unnecessary things.

Comment: @Eddy_Em actually there are (or at least were) cases when Linux does such things with hotplug, but never with umount.